Integrate LDAP with elasticsearch it's works but once i add role_mapping attribute, my elasticsearch container goes down


cluster.name: docker-cluster
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack:
  security:
    authc:
      realms:
        ldap:
          ldap1:
            order: 0
            url: "ldap://ip"
            bind_dn: "CN=admin,DC=example,DC=com"
              # bind_password: "password"
            user_search:
              base_dn: "CN=devops,OU=groups,DC=exapmle,DC=com"
              filter: "(uid={0})"
            group_search:
              base_dn: "OU=groups,DC=example,DC=com"
            files:
              role_mapping: "/root/docker-elk-copy/elasticsearch/config/role_map.yml"
            unmapped_groups_as_roles: false



while Integrate LDAP with elasticsearch it's works but once i add role_mapping attribute, my elasticsearch container goes down?unable to access kibana UI also why ?
I need to access Kibana with my LDAP users

"/root/docker-elk-copy/elasticsearch/config/role_map.yml"
superuser:

"UID=vivek,CN=devops,OU=groups,DC=piltismart,DC=com"

